# Parts of some programs in Windows 10 are cut off

Tags: windows, resolution, display-settings

When running some programs in Windows 10, the top and bottom of the window is cut off, and the mouse does not behave as expected. Once such program that this happens with is QB64, as shown in this image:
[image: QB64]

As you can see, the menu bar at the top of QB64, as well as the status bar at the bottom, are missing, and the same happens with the program once it is run.
Another problem this is causing is that the program 'thinks' that the mouse is higher up than it is, making clicking on items frustrating. In the following image of Blender, my mouse is over one button, yet the one above is selected.
[image: Blender]

Everything that I am using is up to date, including the device drivers, and I am using an HP Pavilion Laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have a known Intel driver issue - roll back to the last driver or see if there's a newer one available.

This is from the help wiki of an online 'game', Second Life,  I help support...

> **Viewer Screen Is Too Large, Top Menu Bar Is Missing, and Click Area Is Too Low**
>
> This is a known issue with recent Intel graphics drivers, affecting
>   other graphics applications besides SL viewers.
>
> Many people have received this graphics driver update without
>   realizing it. The problem sometimes appears after a crash. Many users
>   on HP laptops with OEM drivers are having this problem, although it is
>   also affecting others. What to do:
>
> Try rolling back to a previous driver that worked for you. See
>   https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/000008628.html
>   for instructions.
>
> Some users have reported that the following newer driver fixes the
>   problem: Intel® Graphics Driver for Windows* [15.46] Version:
>   15.46.05.4771 (Latest) Date: 8/23/2017. Download from https://downloadcenter.intel.com. This driver may or may not be
>   available to you depending on your computer.

Source: http://wiki.phoenixviewer.com/fs_intel_issues

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer - I'll give that a go now

Comment: I've tried the exact version of the driver mentioned in your answer, but I get the error 'The driver being installed is not validated for this computer' - it seems to say something about needing a specific driver from HP rather than Intel. Is there somewhere that I can get this from?

Comment: You'll have to nag HP - they're one of the lappy manufacturers that limits which drivers you can install. Alternatively, roll back instead.

Comment: Tried downloading one from the HP website, but with their suggested one, it says that my laptop does not meet the minimum requirements.

Comment: Also, the roll back button is greyed out

Comment: @user4888828 - You can download older versions of the drive off the Intel website.  Hence the reason, Tetsujin's quote, indicate you use the Intel Download Center not HP's website.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue for myself - simply by going into device manager and uninstalling the graphics device. After a restart, it automatically installed an older version, and the problem was fixed.